# jsp print variable inside of <jsp:attribute>

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

How can I print a HTTP Request parameter inside of a `<jsp:body>`?

The following doesn't work.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<t:basePage>
   <jsp:attribute name="title">Reset Password</jsp:attribute>
   <jsp:attribute name="lib">lib/</jsp:attribute>
   <jsp:attribute name="bodyClass">loginPage</jsp:attribute>
   <jsp:body>
      <%= request.getParameter("msg"); %>
   </jsp:body>
</t:basePage>
```

I get this error: 
`HTTP Status 500 - /message.jsp (line: 39, column: 22) Scripting elements ( &lt;%!, &lt;jsp:declaration, &lt;%=, &lt;jsp:expression, &lt;%, &lt;jsp:scriptlet ) are disallowed here.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)

```
${requestScope.param.msg}
```

OR simply

```
 ${msg}
```

may be your configuration disables scripting elements.

**EDIT**

This does not relate to your current requirement since scripting elements seem to be disabled at your end. However the below is syntactically incorrect

```
<%= request.getParameter("msg"); %>
```

You must never add a `;` after `expression_here` `<%= #expression_here %>`

for the simple reason that it translates to `out.print(msg;);` which is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: how is requestScope.msg defined?

Comment: Aren't you familiar with EL ? I assumed you are.

Comment: `requestScope` is an EL implicit (Map) variable which gives a way to access HTTP request parameters.

Comment: Ok, it should have been `param`.

Comment: Ok, but `requestScope.msg` was not defined. `requestScope.param.msg` is.

Comment: The confusion here actually was `requestScope` which is an EL implicit map variable of request attributes and not request parameters. It offers a read-only view of the parameters through its `requestScope.request` object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16607/discussion-between-verisimilitude-and-patrick-lorio)